# GGPlot Not using correct colors from paired column of hexcodes?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am looking to color my points on my scatter plot by the hexcode assigned to each observation in an adjacent column in my data frame. I have tried this code:

```
 ggplot(Data, aes(x = Y, y = X)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = hexcode, color = hexcode), alpha = 1)
```

Which yields this plot:
[image]

The plotted points are not the correct colors. For example, #002244 is a dark blue, but on the plot it's showing up as orange. Also, I'm not sure why the legend is showing up. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help!

Data:

```
structure(list(X = c(17L, 26L, 33L, 58L, 44L, 6L, 82L, 37L, 81L, 
35L, 20L, 52L, 68L, 32L, 83L, 41L, 80L, 70L, 65L, 40L, 11L, 27L, 
16L, 14L, 10L, 77L, 22L, 90L, 42L, 57L, 85L, 71L, 2L, 69L, 18L, 
67L, 9L, 66L, 21L, 43L, 30L, 73L, 87L, 89L, 29L, 19L, 93L, 60L, 
75L, 79L, 3L, 1L, 53L, 48L, 61L, 78L, 84L, 50L, 54L, 31L, 56L, 
4L, 96L, 76L, 47L, 91L, 5L, 8L, 28L, 13L, 12L, 95L, 7L, 55L, 
74L, 46L, 94L, 45L, 36L, 23L, 51L, 62L, 15L, 64L, 34L, 92L, 39L, 
59L, 49L, 88L, 86L, 25L, 72L, 63L, 24L, 38L), Y = c(12L, 36L, 
57L, 47L, 22L, 84L, 49L, 92L, 9L, 60L, 77L, 7L, 52L, 75L, 82L, 
43L, 50L, 33L, 41L, 39L, 25L, 44L, 42L, 35L, 23L, 30L, 91L, 10L, 
29L, 15L, 59L, 17L, 71L, 69L, 64L, 21L, 56L, 5L, 83L, 70L, 40L, 
76L, 61L, 67L, 18L, 90L, 28L, 51L, 89L, 85L, 19L, 48L, 14L, 34L, 
86L, 87L, 78L, 63L, 80L, 93L, 32L, 54L, 81L, 95L, 8L, 24L, 79L, 
27L, 4L, 53L, 11L, 45L, 68L, 74L, 1L, 94L, 37L, 88L, 13L, 46L, 
66L, 2L, 72L, 96L, 55L, 20L, 26L, 3L, 58L, 16L, 6L, 38L, 73L, 
31L, 62L, 65L), hexcode = c("#0b2265", "#4f2683", "#9f8958", 
"#004953", "#002244", "#002244", "#a71930", "#03202f", "#000000", 
"#aa0000", "#d50a0a", "#241773", "#002c5f", "#00338d", "#fb4f14", 
"#000000", "#008e97", "#000000", "#002244", "#002244", "#002244", 
"#0085ca", "#e31837", "#002244", "#773141", "#97233f", "#203731", 
"#005a8b", "#0b162a", "#203731", "#a5acaf", "#002244", "#0b162a", 
"#203731", "#e31837", "#000000", "#002244", "#fb4f14", "#203731", 
"#004953", "#0085ca", "#002244", "#a71930", "#00338d", "#773141", 
"#241773", "#4f2683", "#008e97", "#000000", "#002244", "#002244", 
"#002c5f", "#005a8b", "#97233f", "#d50a0a", "#002244", "#aa0000", 
"#0b2265", "#002244", "#000000", "#002244", "#a5acaf", "#9f8958", 
"#03202f", "#03202f", "#e31837", "#008e97", "#fb4f14", "#002c5f", 
"#a71930", "#002244", "#773141", "#203731", "#0b162a", "#004953", 
"#a5acaf", "#002244", "#203731", "#241773", "#00338d", "#0085ca", 
"#000000", "#005a8b", "#4f2683", "#9f8958", "#aa0000", "#d50a0a", 
"#000000", "#97233f", "#002244", "#002244", "#002244", "#0b2265", 
"#000000", "#002244", "#002244")), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two approaches will work

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Y, y = X)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1, color = Data$hexcode)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Y, y = X, color = hexcode)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't accept this answer yet but I will as soon as stack lets me